# Where did the usage bar go in itunes 12.5.1.21?

Tags: itunes

it used to be at the bottom along with the sync button.
I see no bar and button anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on the correct page?

If you can see this icon, then you're not. Click it.

[image]